# vue init nativescript-vue/vue-cli doesn't generate src folder

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am trying to learn NativeScript-VUE and following this tutorial to connect SQLite to NativeScript.

Following commands were issued.

```
vue init nativescript-vue/vue-cli-template vuex-project

cd vuex-project

npm install
```

Everything ended up without any errors.

But vuex-project directory structure doesn't have an "src" folder to go ahead with the tutorial. Should we have to manually create them?

Edit:
The tutorial I am following is https://www.nativescript.org/blog/data-management-with-sqlite-and-vuex-in-a-nativescript-vue-app

Comment: Have you checked on permission issues?

Comment: what is the version of your cli? vue --version

Comment: No permission problem and all other files are created. vue version is 3.4.0

Answer (score 0):

I do not know which tutorial you are following. But the command that you are using,that does not create a `src` folder. You can find `App.vue` file inside vuex-project/app/components.

You can also have a look tsconfig.json that will show you

```
"paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "app/*"
      ]
     },
```

Comment: I am using the following tutorial and they discuss how to add some codes to the index.js inside src folder.   https://www.nativescript.org/blog/data-management-with-sqlite-and-vuex-in-a-nativescript-vue-app

Answer (score 0):

The [tutorial](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/data-management-with-sqlite-and-vuex-in-a-nativescript-vue-app) you are referring to, is over a year older. It should have been built on the [earlier version](https://github.com/nativescript-vue/vue-cli-template/tree/legacy/template) of CLI template, the [latest version](https://github.com/nativescript-vue/vue-cli-template/tree/master/template) uses `app` instead of `src`.